# IntelliJ Idea not generate id in R.java

Tags: java, android, compilation, intellij-idea

I recently switched to IntelliJ Idea 12.

Now created a project on android and immediately ran into a problem: not generated id in R.java

Rebuild project does not help.

Maybe in IntelliJ Idea have any subtlety is not known to me?

error:

```
12-01 16:08:15.067: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:266)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3624)
at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity.invalidateCounters(MyActivity.java:41)
at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity.access$000(MyActivity.java:11)
at com.example.poem_new.MyActivity$1.onTextChanged(MyActivity.java:29)
at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8027)
at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8074)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8454)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:892)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:669)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:188)
at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:149)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:315)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

R.java file is empty:

```
    /* This stub is for using by IDE only. It is NOT the R class actually packed into APK */
public final class R {
}
```

Comment: Could you uncheck "use external build" in compiler options section

Comment: I have this same issue. The project builds fine in Intellij 11, but doesn't compile the resources in 12

Comment: I have this same issue. My work around was to open Intellij 11 add the new android library, build it and then go back and open 12. It worked fine after. Seems there is an issue in Intellij 12 with adding dependencies?

Comment: I have my project set up as a Maven build. When Intellij fails to regenerate R.java, I just do a Maven build. BTW, I'm pretty sure that I was having this issue with 11 too, but just started doing Android development around the same time that I switched to 12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're observing is probably the by-design behaviour in Idea 12:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99045

> "It is behaviour of IDEA 12, it doesn't generate full R.java in gen folder, it generates it in the IDEA's system dir during compilation."

In your case, look into `~/.IntelliJIdea12\system\compiler\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.RANDOM_STRING\.generated\aapt\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.RANDOM_STRING\production\package\R.java`

This file should be up to date and it should contain all the IDs you expect.

It should also be hooked up to Idea's functionalities of autocompletion, usage search etc by some sort of internal Idea magic.

The empty R.java is normal (although misleading, and Jetbrains intends to change this behaviour).

Comment: FYI I found my R.java in ~./IdeaIC12/system/compile-server/PROJECT_NAME_STRING/android/generated_sources/APP_NAME/aapt/com/packagename/R.java!

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts finding this.  This is an absolutely terrible system given that some errors are so dependent on looking up the R ids.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem. Being tired of Eclipse, I decided to try a new IDE.
I created a new project for Android and inside a new module (trying to make Beginning Android examples to compile and run). When I created a new module it created the usual directories that you expect, including gen. I copied the source files, the manifest and the res directory.
Run into this issue, were IDEA could not figure out what R. was. I did the following:

- remove import of android.R
- delete gen directory

After a clear build gen reappeared and the project was ok.

Hoje it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Closing all intellij windows, renaming the project folder and opening it again solved my problem.

UPDATE:

Intellij tends to save generated files in it's own folder in users documents. So another way for this situation is to invalidate cache files. Go to file menu and select invalidate caches, then intellij will restart and it regenerate caches and other required files and everything will be ok!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your layout doesn't have anything in it. If you expand your res/layout directory in your project, double click on the main.xml file. Just add a button or something and give it an id. That should worl

Answer (score -1):

This problem is come if Your Project java complier is differents than your android java compiler.Change the Project Setting and clean project is working.
if problem is not solving then goto project properties->android -> select any android version
then compile

Comment: How to clean project in IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: go to Project menu option select clean and select your project or all project project->clean->single/all

Comment: may be Structure of IntelliJ IDEA Project? I can't find "Project menu"

Comment: In Eclipse Menu Section you can see the Project in the middle of refactor and Search

Comment: Why in Eclipse? I have a problem in IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: In Idea it's Build->Rebuild. Try to regenerate R file and ensure it is generated without warnings and errors: one time a had similar bug when i had error in XML and idea just silently generated empty R.java

Answer (score -4):

Make lines of code in comments where you are using "R.id" and then run your project.

then for next time remove comments and run it again.

Hopefully it will work

Comment: Why this must help me? It's not an resolving.