# Android Studio R.java

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm seeing a crash on an older device that works on multiple newer devices:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030035
```

If I recall correctly you could look at the R.java to see the culprit, however in Android Studio it doesn't seem to exist.  Where is the R.java so I can correlate that ID?

Thanks.

Comment: If that happens only on older devices you probably used an android resource that does not yet exist on them (`android.R. ...`)

Comment: I'd agree except that this is a legacy piece of code that won't work.  It was originally designed on 2.3 which is what it's failing on now...I haven't tested on it in ages...it may be somoe odd Android Studio bug.

Comment: The actual generated R.java is located here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683639/650322

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Android Studio 1.1.0 the R.java file is under

```
Project/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com.android.'projectname'/R.java
```

If you don't see the above collection of folders, clean and build the project first. It takes a few minutes and you'll see Gradle running at the bottom of the IDE.

Comment: The file is empty.

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 3.4 and above that the R.java file is under

Project/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResourc/r/com/{app package name} / R. java

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]**
**LOCATION OF R.JAVA file in Android Studio 1.3.1 is as follows:**

In Android Studio, go to the Project Window (usually on the left-hand side pane:

1. Right-click on the node, **app**
2. Click on **"Show In Explorer"**. This will open the actual directory/location of your project.
3. The path of the R.java file in this directory is as follows:
   **app\build\generated\source\r\debug**\com\sg\calculator 
   (Since, I used the package name com.sg.calculator for my project, hence, I had to go inside the folder com\sg\calculator. This will be obviously different for your project).

Answer (score 0):

May be try thus.

Goto File -> Settings -> Compiler now check use external build

then rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

### Android Studio (Preview) 0.5.9

If you are using Android Studio (Preview) 0.5.9 and the new Gradle build tool you can find the default `R.java` in your IDE here:

```
build/source/r/release/com/google/android/gms/R.java
```

and your own here:

```
build/source/r/release/com/company/android/R.java
```

Answer (score 0):

So this took a lot of trial and error and google searches but finally have cracked it. After renaming your Android Project in

- `File --> Project Structure`, go to Android Manifest and rename the package manually. Then close Android Studio.
- Go to your Android project in the explorer, then `App --> src --> main --> java --> com`. Here, rename the folder  `companyname` to your `new companyname`.
- Open this folder, and rename the `gamename` folder to your gamename, in the same format and spelling as you did in Project Structure. Now open Android Studio again.
- `Go to App --> java --> com --> companyname.gamename` (this should be showing as the name you gave it in the explorer). Open `PTPlayer` and manually update the package name to the new package name.
- This should resolve your problem of `Cannot REsolve R`