# App crashes when run on <25 sdk

Tags: java, android, gradle, resources

I've built an app and during the design process was always testing it on an emulator with sdk 25. Now I ran it on emulators with sdk 24 and 23 and it crashes without stopping at any breakpoints (including the system ones).
So, below is monitoring report. I can see that something is wrong with resources, but  I can't figure out what exactly. 
What confuses me the most is that it runs perfectly on sdk 25.

So far I've cleaned my project with AS tool.

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-23 19:29:04.167 3037-3037/com.labfoodandfriends.walley E/AndroidRuntime:
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.labfoodandfriends.walley, PID: 3037
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040048
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at com.labfoodandfriends.walley.mFragments.TodayStats.onCreateView(TodayStats.java:53)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(
05-23 19:34:04.196 3037-3037/com.labfoodandfriends.walley I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3037 SIG: 9
```

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('src/main/libs/opencsv-3.9.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I had some layouts built for v25 only. So I created their copies and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

It is an XML error. So, breakpoints aren't gonna work. There is a resource missing in one of your XML Resource files.

> Resource ID #0x7f040048

You can recheck it in your R.java file (if it exists or not)

Also, if it exists make sure that you have declared this id at proper location. If this id is being accessed in your XML file before it is declared. You might see this error.

Comment: Thank you. How can I check the R.java. Can I locate it from within Android Studio?

Comment: Refer to this [Android Studio R.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525374/android-studio-r-java)